# WSDL to Apex <foo a="b"><bar>baz</bar></foo> to <foo bar="baz">bar</foo>

Tags: soap, wsdl2apex

### Problem

I imported a WSDL to Apex Class.

And generate the next class:

```
public class MyService {
   public class bar {
      public String bar;
      private String[] bar_type_info = new String[] {'bar','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','true'};
      private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[] {'http://schema.myservice.com', 'false', 'false'};
      private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[] {'bar'};
   }

   public class foo {
      public MyService.bar bar;
      public String a;
      private String[] bar_type_info = new String[] {'bar','http://schema.myservice.com','bar','0','1','true'};
      private String[] a_att_info = new String[] {'a'};
      private String apex_schema_type_info = new String[] {'http://schema.myservice.com','false','false'};
      private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[] {'bar'};
   }
}
```

When  I do the callout the generated xml request  is `<foo a="b"><bar>baz</bar></foo>` and I need `<foo bar="baz">bar</foo>`.

### Question

What do I need change in this class to do this?

Comment: Why is the WSDL wrong?  You should contact the administrator of the service you are hitting to get them to generate the correct WSDL for their service.

Comment: Are you able to share your WSDL? Feel free to change the endpoint URL. I suspect the required XML will be difficult to generate as you need a string member on `foo` to contain the attribute information and you also need foo to be a string so that it isn't generated as a nested element.